# Eclipse RCP: how to export launch configuration plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-fragment

***Note:** This is not a duplicate of any question regarding problems with product export: I can already export successfully both within gui and with headless pde build.*

I am developing a RCP application on eclipse Indigo (3.7), which is in the final stages before release. The branding product, in its own plugin, is feature based and includes:

> - myapp main (and unique) feature
> - org.eclipse.rcp
> - org.eclipse.equinox.p2.feature
> - org.eclipse.help

The main feature collects (includes) all of the plugins composing the application plus the minimum required set of plugins from org.eclipse.rcp and org.eclipse.equinox.p2 features; it depends on the plugins needed for p2 self-provisioning and the minimum set of platform plugins needed for my application to run.

Then I had to add translations, and added a snapshot of eclipse-babel to the target.

This is the situation:

- I synchronize the product
- I launch the product generating a new launch configuration

  - --> only some parts of the GUI are translated
- I open launch configuration - plugins tab - and click "add required plugins"
- The number of included plugins increases (from about 130 to about 180)

  - --> now when I start the application everything is translated

So I had to manually copy the fragments included in the launch after clicking "select required", to the feature includes (only the fragments containing translation, actually). That fixed it.

Question: is there a method to export the list of plugins *currently* selected in the launch configuration? or any other method which synchronizes what is included in the launch configuration with what is included in the feature (*not* the contrary)?

Answer (score 2):

`File->Export->Launch` Configuration doesn't work for you?

Comment: yes it does work, but the exported file is xml with the plugin list in a single attribute (comma separated). synchronizing that list to the feature.xml would need the same manual work as using the gui. What i want is something that adds to the feature the plugins that are missing compared to the current launch configuration.